# Отключить автоматическую вставку в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

При открытии файла вместо обычного курсора стоит вставка , приходится каждый раз нажимать клавишу insert, как можно ее отключить? Переустановка программы не помогла решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да такая проблема в сети встречается довольно часто. Один из [советов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165756/cursor-overwrite-mode-in-vscode), это установить [данное](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adammaras.overtype) расширение которое должно помочь, а там уже можно писать правила, как например это:

```
"overtype.paste": true
```

[Вот](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1012) обсуждение данной проблемы.